# Date convert dd-MMM-yyyy to dd-MM-yyyy in java

Tags: java, date

What is the simplest way to convert 23-Mar-2011 to 23-03-2011 in Java?

---

Thanks everyone. This seem to solve the issue:

```
try { 
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").parse("24-Nov-2002")); 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime())); 
} catch (ParseException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Comment: Thanks everyone found the answer.`try {
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").parse("24-Nov-2002"));
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
   System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
  } catch (ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you looked at [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) ?

Comment: Yes, I did. But getting a java.text.ParseException

Comment: you are always welcome (also to upvote/mark it as answer , as it is for you)

Answer (score 13):

Try this

```
String strDate="23-Mar-2011";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
try {
    Date varDate=dateFormat.parse(strDate);
    dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    System.out.println("Date :"+dateFormat.format(varDate));
}catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler version of your code:

```
DateFormat shortFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
DateFormat mediumFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
String s = "23-Mar-2011";
String shortDate = shortFormat.format(mediumFormat.parse(s));
System.out.println(shortDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

> SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
>
> SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
>
> Date date = format1.parse("24-Nov-2002");
>
> System.out.println(format2.format(date));