# Getting date in format dd-MMM-yyyy

Tags: java, date

I have the below method as shown below in which date is coming as of string:

```
public static java.sql.Date  getSimpleDate11(String dateString) {

if (dateString == null) {
    return null;
}
java.util.Date date = null;
java.sql.Date sqlDate =null ;
try {

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    df.setLenient(false);
    date = df.parse(dateString);
     sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());


} catch (ParseException pe) {
    throw new RuntimeException("The date entered is invalid or has incorrect format"+ dateString);
}
return sqlDate;
```

Now I want to change the format: I want to store the date in the format dd-MMM-yyyy.

What should I do?

Comment: 2014-07-23 is the input string

Comment: And now you want `23-JUL-2014`?

Comment: What is the code you're trying to execute, your actual input, your expected output, and your actual output?

Comment: @Maba yes I want in the format 23-JUL-2014

Comment: Do what @JBNizet says. Update your question with more info.

Comment: `new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(theDate).toUpperCase()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date convert dd-MMM-yyyy to dd-MM-yyyy in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401236/date-convert-dd-mmm-yyyy-to-dd-mm-yyyy-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

> *now I want to change the format I want to store the date in the format `dd-MMM-yyyy`*

You don't need an explicit conversion into the requested date format `dd-MMM-yyyy`.
Dates are not directly concerned with date formats. Your SQL Driver class will convert to proper database specific format before inserting into a date field of database table.

**Using MySQL Driver**:

```
// this statement will cause sql date as '2014-03-21'  
new java.sql.Date( new java.until.Date().getTime() );
```

In most of the databases the default format is `YYYY-MM-DD`.

**Example (MySQL)**:

```
mysql> show variables like 'date_format';
+---------------+----------+
| Variable_name | Value    |
+---------------+----------+
| date_format   | %Y-%m-%d |
+---------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select curdate();
+------------+
| curdate()  |
+------------+
| 2014-03-21 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```

**Detailed Example**:

```
public class SimpleDateFormat_Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String dateInputPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd"; // numeric 2 digit month
        String dateTargetPattern = "yyyy-MMM-dd"; // For 3 char month name
        String dateString = "2014-03-20";

        patternTest( dateInputPattern, dateString, dateTargetPattern );

        System.out.println();

        // day of month first and then 2 digit month
        dateInputPattern = "yyyy-dd-MM";  
        dateString = "2014-21-03";
        dateTargetPattern = "yyyy-MMMM-dd, EEEE"; // for Full month name

        patternTest( dateInputPattern, dateString, dateTargetPattern );
    } // psvm( ... )

    public static void 
    patternTest( String dateInputPattern, 
                 String dateString, 
                 String dateTargetPattern ) throws Exception {
        java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = 
            new java.text.SimpleDateFormat( dateInputPattern );
        java.util.Date date = sdf.parse( dateString );

        System.out.println( "Date Pattern: " + dateInputPattern );
        System.out.println( "Date String : " + dateString );
        System.out.println( "Date Value  : " + date );
        sdf.applyPattern( dateTargetPattern );
        System.out.println( "Target Pattern: " + dateTargetPattern );
        System.out.println( "Pattern based Date Value: " + sdf.format(date) );

        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date( date.getTime() );
        System.out.println( "But, SQL Date: " + sqlDate );
    } // patternTest( s, s, s )
} // end of class SimpleDateFormat_Example
```

If you run the above program you would be seeing following results.

**Results**:

```
Date Pattern: yyyy-MM-dd
Date String : 2014-03-20
Date Value  : Thu Mar 20 00:00:00 IST 2014
Target Pattern: yyyy-MMM-dd
Pattern Formatted Date Value: 2014-Mar-20
But, SQL Date: 2014-03-20

Date Pattern: yyyy-dd-MM
Date String : 2014-21-03
Date Value  : Fri Mar 21 00:00:00 IST 2014
Target Pattern: yyyy-MMMM-dd, EEEE
Pattern Formatted Date Value: 2014-March-21, Friday
But, SQL Date: 2014-03-21
```

Have a close look at SQL Date, it has the same pattern in all the outputs. The same is also matching with the result of `select curdate()` pattern, as shown in top of this answer.

**Conclusion**:

Though you set and apply specific pattern, in your scripting language, for a date type database field, it would only be stored in the `default` pattern defined for the database date types.

Hence, converting a pattern from `yyyy-MM-dd` to `yyyy-MMM-dd` and sending to database will not affect and change anything.

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
String PATTERN="yyyy-MM-dd";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat();
dateFormat.applyPattern(PATTERN);
String date1=dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Comment: Right.  It must be very hard to see where asiya has specified the pattern, and change it to the pattern that you want.

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.Date.getTime()` method returns the number of milliseconds since `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT` represented by this Date object.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

     String dateString="2014-03-21";
     DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
     Date date=df.parse(dateString);
     System.out.println("date:"+date);
     df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
     System.out.println("Formated Date:"+df.format(date));
     System.out.println("date.getTime"+date.getTime());


}
```